# Protocol Oriented Programming Example not working in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift3, protocols

I have the following piece of code where am trying to implement my Zoo example using `Structs` and `Protocols`.

In the example, I have a Zoo where there is certain type of animals which have a certain type of characteristics. Details of the question are in the Readme file of repo (https://github.com/harsh62/Melbournce-Zoo/blob/master/README.md)

I want to understand whether what am trying to do is the correct approach or not? The following piece of code compiles without any errors but doesn't work.

Can somebody help, please?

```
enum Sex {
    case Male
    case Female
    case Other
}

enum Size:Int {
    case ExtraSmall = 0
    case Small = 1
    case Medium = 2
    case Large = 3
    case ExtraLarge = 4

}

enum Diet {
    case Herbivore
    case Carnivore
}

protocol Animal {
    var sex: Sex { get set }
    var size: Size { get set }
    var diet: Diet { get set }
    var weight: Double { get set }
    var age: Int { get set }
}

protocol Swimmable {
    var swimSpeed: Double { set get }
}

protocol NeedsEclosure {
    func enclosureSize() -> Double
}

protocol Carnivorous {
    func meatSize() -> Double
}

protocol Mammal { }

protocol Fish {
    var adjustedSpeed: Double { set get }
}

protocol Bird { }

protocol Reptile { }

protocol Invertebrate { }

/////Extensions to protocols

extension Animal {
    var weight: Double {
        set {
           self.weight = newValue
        }
        get {
            return weight
        }
    }
    var age: Int{
        set {
           self.age = newValue
        }
        get {
            return age
        }
    }
    var size: Size{
        set {
            self.size = newValue
        }
        get {
            return size
        }
    }
    var diet: Diet{
        set {
            self.diet = newValue
        }
        get {
            return diet
        }
    }
    var sex: Sex{
        set {
            self.sex = newValue
        }
        get {
            return sex
        }
    }
}

extension Swimmable {
    var swimSpeed: Double{
        set {
            self.swimSpeed = newValue
        }
        get {
            return swimSpeed
        }
    }
}

extension NeedsEclosure where Self: Animal {
    func enclosureSize() -> Double {
        return Double(size.rawValue) * weight
    }
}

extension Carnivorous where Self: Animal {
    func meatSize() -> Double {
        return Double(size.rawValue) * weight
    }
}

extension Swimmable where Self: Animal {
    var adjustedSpeed: Double { return (swimSpeed/weight)/Double(age) }
}

/////////////////////////////////
typealias BigCat =  Animal & Mammal & Swimmable & Carnivorous & NeedsEclosure

struct Tiger: BigCat { }

var tiger = Tiger()
tiger.enclosureSize()
```

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work". What output or outcome do you get?  What do you expect/want?

Comment: I want my struct to print `enclosureSize` using the `Tiger` struct, which is not happening and the playground crashes.

Comment: You haven't assigned any property values in the code you have shown.

Comment: It doesn't ask for anything. If I try to initialize, it throws an error saying `Argument passed to call that takes no Argument.`

Comment: You haven't defined any initialisers so you will need to set the various properties after you create the tiger. Eg.  `tiger.weight = 50`.

Comment: But why doesn't it allow me to initialize my struct with all the default values at once? And if i try to set the property as you suggested it is throwing a bad excess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137725/discussion-between-paulw11-and-harsh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `extension` of `Animal` where you define all of those computed properties makes no sense. You need stored properties. It makes no sense for a computed getter, `weight` for example, to `return weight`. Likewise, the computed setter, `self.weight = weight` doesn't make sense.

You need stored properties to store all of these values, and stored properties cannot be implemented in a protocol extension. Consider your protocol for `Animal`:

```
protocol Animal {
    var sex: Sex { get set }
    var size: Size { get set }
    var diet: Diet { get set }
    var weight: Double { get set }
    var age: Int { get set }
}
```

You really need to hold all these values somewhere, you can't use computed properties defined in a protocol extension. (So get rid of that `extension` for `Animal` that defines those invalid computed properties.) You actually want to implement these stored properties inside the type that conforms to this protocol, e.g.:

```
typealias BigCat = Animal & Mammal & Swimmable & Carnivorous & NeedsEnclosure

struct Tiger: BigCat {
    var swimSpeed = 2.0
    var size = Size.large
    var sex = Sex.male
    var diet = Diet.carnivore
    var weight = 400.0
    var age = 4
}
```

(By the way, I changed the values of those various `enum` types to use lowercase letter, as is the convention in Swift 3.)

Your protocol extensions can provide default implementations for methods and computed properties, but not for stored properties.

Comment: The approach which I have tried to follow, is this correct in terms of modularity, reusability and POP priciples and is this correct way to design in terms of the problem statement given here https://github.com/harsh62/Melbournce-Zoo/blob/master/README.md ?